# Show Ajax error response as a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

from an Ajax call that was build up like this:

```
 function GetData() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Model.RouteForAjaxLastValue",//"/RCharts/AjaxMethod",//
            data: "{Id: " + lastID+ "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {

            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        })
```

I sometimes get responses like this:

[image: Error-Message as Alert]

I can see that this is meant to be displayed as a webpage since its an entire page html formatted.

But is there a way to display that directly as a new page mabye?

It cuts of the rest of the message in the alert before I can even get to read what the error may be...

Comment: You can also set this html to some div element may be and you can also check the response in developer tools' network tabs' response section of the request;

Comment: Why you are sending entire page html instead of sending some `JSON` format data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use `console.log()`

but this should append it to the body:

```
$('body').append(response.responseText);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("html").html(response.responseText);` inside your success function .

```
success : function(response){
  $("html").html(response.responseText);
}
```

Comment: 1. This will replace the entire page with the response. 2. You'll need to use response.responseText since response is an object and not a string. (or use stringify)

Comment: @Kolby definately .. `responseText` . I think he also need to replace the entire page.